# Sinatra routes not working in modular app?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I've converted a classic Sinatra application to a modular application.  Now suddenly my `put`, `patch` and `delete` routes stopped working.  `get` and `post` work fine.  Is there something I need to do to get these to work in a modular app that is different from classic?

```
%form{action: "/addsomething", method: 'post'}
  %input{type: 'hidden', name: '_method', value: 'put'}
```

I get a 404 now when I attempt to access one of the above mentioned routes.

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class MyClass < Sinatra::Base
    put '/addsomething' do
     'HELLO WORLD!'
    end

    get '/hello' do
      'hello world'
    end
 end
```

Comment: You need to show us examples of your code so we can see how you're defining your class, and the handlers. Remember, a picture is worth a thousand words, and in this case, the picture is code.

Comment: Please see the original post.  I edited it with my class.  Thanks.

Comment: Your quotes are mismatched – you’re mixing up single and double quotes.

Comment: Sorry, the quotes was a careless typo because I typed by hand when I did the post.  The quotes are correct in the real thing.

Answer (score 1):

The `method_override` setting (that allows the `_method` field to override the HTTP method) is [false by default in modular style](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Modular%20vs.%20Classic%20Style). You need to enable it with:

```
enable :method_override
```

Comment: Unfortunately method_override is enabled.

Comment: DOH, my bad.  I had :method_overide instead of :method_override.  All fixed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can still inherit from Sinatra::Application in the modular style to keep the default settings:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class MyClass < Sinatra::Application
    put '/addsomething' do
     'HELLO WORLD!'
    end

    get '/hello' do
      'hello world'
    end
 end
```